# Namespacing in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

Is there any intrinsic support for namespacing in coffeescript?

Adequate namespacing seems like something coffeescript could really help with although I don't seem to be able to find anything to suggest that there is support for this.

Comment: You have auto-closured files, isn't that enough?

Comment: You have to elaborate on what you mean by "namespacing." It's an ambiguous term.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A way to make it simple to reference the class both in it's own "namespace" (the closed function) and the global namespace is to assign it immediately. Example:

```
# Define namespace unless it already exists
window.Test or= {}

# Create a class in the namespace and locally
window.Test.MyClass = class MyClass
  constructor: (@a) ->

# Alerts 3
alert new Test.MyClass(1).a + new MyClass(2).a
```

As you see, now you can refer to it as `MyClass` within the file, but if you need it outside it's available as `Test.MyClass`. If you only want it in the Test namespace you can simplify it even more:

```
window.Test or= {}

# Create only in the namespace
class window.Test.MyClass
  constructor: (@a) ->
```

Comment: A key thing here is window. My compiler errors without it.

Answer (score 35):

I prefer using this pattern for "namespacing". It isn't really a namespace but an object tree, but it does the job:

Somewhere in the startup of the app, you define the namespaces globally (replace `window` with `exports` or `global` based on your environment.

```
window.App =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
```

Then, when you want to declare classes, you can do so:

```
class App.Models.MyModel
  # The class is namespaced in App.Models
```

And when you want to reference it:

```
myModel = new App.Models.MyModel()
```

If you don't like the global way of defining namespaces, you can do so before your class:

```
window.App.Models ?= {} # Create the "namespace" if Models does not already exist.
class App.Models.MyModel
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to use `window.App.Models` here. Just `App.Models ?= {}` will do.

Comment: Correct.  I like reference `window.` in my assignments in order to be explicit that I mean to make a global assignment.  Just a coding style thing for me.

Answer (score 10):

Here's my personal implementation :

https://github.com/MaksJS/Namespace-in-CoffeeScript

How to use in the browser :

```
namespace Foo:SubPackage1:SubPackage2:
  class Bar extends Baz
    #[...]
```

How to use in CommonJS environment :

```
require './path/to/this/file' # once

namespace Foo:SubPackage1:SubPackage2:
  class Bar extends Baz
    #[...]
```

Comment: I like this option, it's nice and clean, and fits well with the coffee script syntax. +1'd

Comment: I also like this solution pretty much but the IntelliJ IDEA does a line-break after each ":" when auto-formatting the CoffeeScript code which breaks then file :(

Comment: This breaks under most compression libraries (e.g. your minified version will not work). The Classes under the namespace names get mangled.

Answer (score 5):

From the section about namespacing on the wiki: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/FAQ

```
# Code:
#
namespace = (target, name, block) ->
  [target, name, block] = [(if typeof exports isnt 'undefined' then exports else window), arguments...] if arguments.length < 3
  top    = target
  target = target[item] or= {} for item in name.split '.'
  block target, top

# Usage:
#
namespace 'Hello.World', (exports) ->
  # `exports` is where you attach namespace members
  exports.hi = -> console.log 'Hi World!'

namespace 'Say.Hello', (exports, top) ->
  # `top` is a reference to the main namespace
  exports.fn = -> top.Hello.World.hi()

Say.Hello.fn()  # prints 'Hi World!'
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is a popular pattern in CoffeeScript. People typically just write `exports.foo = bar` directly.

Answer (score 3):

You must really check out CoffeeToaster:
https://github.com/serpentem/coffee-toaster

It comes with a packaging system that when enabled will use your folder's hierarchy as namespaces declarations to your classes if you want so, then you can extends classes from multiple files, do imports and son, such as like:

```
#<< another/package/myclass
class SomeClass extends another.package.MyClass
```

The build configuration is extremely minimalist and simple, made to be obvious:

```
# => SRC FOLDER
toast 'src_folder'
    # => VENDORS (optional)
    # vendors: ['vendors/x.js', 'vendors/y.js', ... ]

    # => OPTIONS (optional, default values listed)
    # bare: false
    # packaging: true
    # expose: ''
    # minify: false

    # => HTTPFOLDER (optional), RELEASE / DEBUG (required)
    httpfolder: 'js'
    release: 'www/js/app.js'
    debug: 'www/js/app-debug.js'
```

There's also a debug option that compile files individually for ease the debugging processes and another useful features.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is possible to write:

```
class MyObject.MyClass
    constructor: () ->
        initializeStuff()
    myfunction: () ->
        doStuff()
```

if you declared an object/ns MyObject.

And while we're at it, here's my implementation of a jquery-ns-function:

```
(function($) {
    $.namespace = function(namespace, initVal) {
        var nsParts = namespace.split("."),
            nsPart = nsParts.shift(),
            parent = window[nsPart] = window[nsPart] || {},
            myGlobal = parent;
        while(nsPart = nsParts.shift()) {
            parent = parent[nsPart] = parent[nsPart] || {};
        }
        return myGlobal;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm also busy to learn the best way of structuring the files and use coffeescript in combination with backbone and cake, I have created a [***small project on github***](https://github.com/pericazivkovic/coffeescript-backbone-sample) to keep it as a reference for myself, maybe it will help you too around cake and some basic things. All .js (with cake compiled files) are in **www** folder so that you can open them in your browser and all source files (except for cake configuration) are in **src** folder. In this example, all .coffee files are compiled and combined in **one** output .js file which is then included in html.

Based on some of the answers here on StackOverflow I have created small util.coffee file (in src folder) that exposes "namespaces" to the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I Strongly suggest using requirejs.org or similar battle tested module loaders.
Especially if you want to load stuff asynchronously.

Rolling your own namespacing/module scheme is really hard if you disregard
the simply, easy and naive approaches